# what is the echo command in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I have a question about clearcase, someone helped me on some issue in clearcase, he used a command as follow: `echo " " > xxx.log` and

```
cleartool co -nc filename
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a file which is "checkedout but removed", as described in [ct ls](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm):

> The element was checked out in this view, but the view-private file was subsequently removed.
>   You may have deleted the file.

A solution to restore that file is to checkout it again, but if you do that directly, ClearCase would complain about being unable to access said file (because it isn't physically there anymore).

Hence the:

```
 echo " " > afile
```

You need to have *some* content in that file in order to make a `cleartool` command on it.
So even if its content is a bogus one, it at least allows you to proceed.

Then, you can checkout it again (`-nc` means without comment, but it also means "takes the previous comments used on the current checked out version)

```
 cleartool checkout -nc afile
```

Another way to restore it is to [**uncheckout** the file](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=107131):

```
 cleartool unco afile
```

That will also restore its content.

Answer (score 0):

The first command writes a space to xxx.log; `echo` is a shell command and has nothing to do with clearcase. The second command checks out filename without comments. These two commands seem to be pretty unrelated, unless there something else you haven't told us.

Comment: the problem is that, I have a file which is checkedout but removed,so we used these commands to remove that file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip:
'echo' might to used to clear xxx.log file.

co - stands for check out filename,
nc - stands for no comments

Might be helpful: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ClearcaseCommands.html